# How to debug startup of app run by SendTo menu

Tags: debugging, delphi, startup

On Windows, I'd like for my FMX app to run from the SendTo context menu. If the app is already running I'd like for the second instance to pass its command line to the first and then exit. Code is below. The problem is that if I have first instance running in the debugger, and then double-click an appropriate file, I see no evidence that the first instance receives a message from a newly started instance. If the app is not already running then the double click starts a new instance as expected.

Is there a way to debug the startup of the instance launched by the SendTo menu?

This code adds the app to the SendTo menu:

```
class procedure TInstallationController.CreateSendTo;
var
    lExePath: string;
    lObject: IUnknown;
    lSLink: IShellLink;
    lPFile: IPersistFile;
    lFolderPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
    lLinkName: WideString;
begin
    SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_SENDTO, 0, 0, lFolderPath);
    lLinkName := Format('%s\%s.lnk', [lFolderPath, 'AppName']);

{$IFNDEF DEBUG}
    if String(lLinkName).Contains('debug') then
        Tfile.Delete(lLinkName);
{$ENDIF DEBUG}
    if not TFile.Exists(lLinkName) then
        if CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) = S_OK then
        begin
            lExePath := ParamStr(0);
            lObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
            lSLink := lObject as IShellLink;
            lPFile := lObject as IPersistFile;

            with lSlink do
            begin
                SetPath(pChar(lExePath));
                SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(TPath.GetDirectoryName(lExePath)));
            end;

            lPFile.Save(PWChar(WideString(lLinkName)), false);
        end;
end;
```

This code is placed before Application.Initialize in the .dpr file:

```
var
    lWindow: HWND;
    lMutex: THandle;
    lCopyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct;
    i: integer;
    lArg: string;
    lResult: DWORD;
begin
    lMutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, PChar('43671EDF1E5A4B419F213336F2387B0D'));
    if lMutex = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    if GetLastError = Error_Already_Exists then
    begin
        FillChar(lCopyDataStruct, Sizeof(lCopyDataStruct), 0);
        for I := 1 to ParamCount do
        begin
            lArg := ParamStr(i);
            lCopyDataStruct.cbData := (Length(lArg) + 1)*SizeOf(Char);
            lCopyDataStruct.lpData := PChar(lArg);
            lWindow := FindWindow('FMT' + STRMainWindowClassName, nil);
            SendMessageTimeout(lWindow, WM_COPYDATA, 0, NativeInt(@lCopyDataStruct),
                SMTO_BLOCK, 3000, @lResult);
        end;

        exit;
    end;
...
end.
```

Assignments in FormCreate of the main form to support Windows message forwarding:

```
...
FHwnd := FmxHandleToHwnd(Handle);
FOldWndProc := GetWindowLongPtr(FHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(FHwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, NativeInt(@WindowProc));
...
```

This forwards Windows messages to my main FMX form:

```
function WindowProc (HWND: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: wParam; lParam: lParam): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := MasterDetailView.WndProc (HWND, Msg, wParam, lParam);
end;
```

This main form method receives forwarded messages:

```
function TViewMasterDetail.WndProc(aHwnd: HWND; aMsg: UINT; aWParam: WPARAM;
    aLParam: LPARAM): LResult;
begin
    Result := 0;

    if aMsg = WM_COPYDATA then
    begin
TUtils.Log('External file: ' + PChar(PCopyDataStruct(aLParam)^.lpData));
        Viewmodel.HandleExternalFile(PChar(PCopyDataStruct(aLParam)^.lpData));
        Exit;
    end;

    result := CallWindowProc(Ptr(fOldWndProc), aHwnd, aMsg, aWParam, aLParam);
end;
```

TViewMasterDetail.WndProc is called many time, but as far as I can tell aMsg is never WM_COPYDATA. The 'External file:' message never appears in the log. Thanks

Comment: Your startup code is not checking whether `FindWindow()` or `SendMessageTimeout()` is failing. For instance, maybe UIPI is blocking your messages. You are also not populating `lCopyDataStruct.dwData` with a unique ID to differentiate your `WM_COPYDATA` messages from other people's `WM_COPYDATA` messages.

Comment: Thank you @Remy. This put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Programmer error. To approximate debugging the startup code I ran a copy of the app outside the debugger and then launched a second copy of the app in the debugger, passing the path to the target file on the command line. This told me FindWindow was failing. I wrote this startup code a long time ago and since then have changed the names of UI classes in the app, including the main window. But I neglected to change the constant I used for the class name of the main window and pass to FindWindow. Fixing the constant cleared the error. Just another win for the evils of using text!

Comment: I'd still also check function results intead of assuming they always return what I want. Even `SHGetFolderPath()` may fail.